# Two ListBoxes with two (almost similar) templates

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, datatemplate, listboxitem

I have 2 Listboxes with 2 data templates that are almost identical except that one of them contains TextBox instead of ComboBox.

First Template :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OldPanelsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type VM:CustomPanelBoard}">
    <Grid Height="60" Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Height="60" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Width="35" Background="Blue"
                Margin="0 0 2 0" >
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" 
                        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                Converter={StaticResource IncrementerConverter}}" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DistributionSystemName}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Number of circuits to be copied: "/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfCircuitsToBeCopied}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Second Template :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewPanelsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type VM:CustomPanelBoard}">
    <Grid Height="60">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Height="60" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Width="35" Background="Blue"
                Margin="0 0 2 0" >
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" 
                        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                Converter={StaticResource IncrementerConverter}}" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  IsHitTestVisible="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" IsEnabled="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DistributionSystemTemplate}" >
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Number of available ways: "/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfAvailableWays}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see they are both almost identical except for this part :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  IsHitTestVisible="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" IsEnabled="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DistributionSystemTemplate}" >
        </ComboBox>
```

The problem is whenever i change anything in one of them i have to change the same thing in the other also ... Any way that can merge them in some way and make the combobox the only variable that changes according to which listbox is calling the template ?

Comment: You can try to set combobox visibility inside datatrigger, when particular condition inside trigger is reached. Or use converter for that. Could you please share the code, where these templates are used?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684923/wpf-parameters-to-datatemplates) it might be helpful

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ... Thanks Pavel , the converter idea with toggling visibility solved the problem .. i Published it as an answer (Thanks again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an attempt on how you can achieve that, but I have to admit that it is messy but answers your question blindly! a better approach would be to properly implement a `DataTemplateSelector`.

The idea is to decouple the changing parts into two separate `DataTemplates` and put them into the resources, one with the `Combobox` and one for the `TextBlock` in your case:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateCombobox">
        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" ...>
        </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTextblock" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DistributionSystemName}" ... />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now those controls will be replaced with a `ContentPresenter` in your main (common) `DataTemplate`. The `ContentPresenter` uses a `ContentTemplateSelector` to select which sub-DataTemplate to used based on the name of the `ListBox` on which this `DataTemplate` is applied, this is why the `Content` is bound directly o the `ListBox` using ancestry binding:

```
 <local:ValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" 
                                     DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateTextblock}" 
                                     ComboboxDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateCombobox}" 
                                     TextBlockDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateTextblock}" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OldPanelsTemplate">
        <Grid Height="60" Margin="0" Name="OldPanelsTemplateGrid" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Height="60" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Width="35" Background="Blue"
                    Margin="0 0 2 0" >
                <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" Text="tex" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">

            </ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Number of circuits to be copied: "/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfCircuitsToBeCopied}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And here how your `DataTemplateSelector` should be implemented (basically):

```
public class ValueDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComboboxDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TextBlockDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var lb = item as ListBox;

        if (lb is null)
            return DefaultDataTemplate;

        if (lb.Name == "ListOne")
            return ComboboxDataTemplate;
        if (lb.Name == "ListTwo")
            return TextBlockDataTemplate;
        return DefaultDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Finally, since your sub-DataTemplates lose their DataContexts due to the `Content` of the `ContentPresenter` being bound to the `ListBox` directly, then just hook their `DataContext`s again using `ElementName` Binding or something:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateCombobox">
        <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OldPanelsTemplateGrid, Path=DataContext}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" >
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTextblock" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DistributionSystemName}"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OldPanelsTemplateGrid, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

`OldPanelsTemplateGrid` is the First Grid in the main `DataTemplate` that should have the valid `ListBoxItem` `DataContext`.

Here is the full Xaml code:

```
   </Window ...
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateCombobox">
        <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OldPanelsTemplateGrid, Path=DataContext}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" >
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTextblock" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DistributionSystemName}"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OldPanelsTemplateGrid, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:ValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" 
                                     DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateTextblock}" 
                                     ComboboxDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateCombobox}" 
                                     TextBlockDataTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateTextblock}" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OldPanelsTemplate">
        <Grid Height="60" Margin="0" Name="OldPanelsTemplateGrid" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Height="60" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Width="35" Background="Blue"
                    Margin="0 0 2 0" >
                <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" Text="tex" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">

            </ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Number of circuits to be copied: "/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfCircuitsToBeCopied}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<!--DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=2,AncestorType=DataTemplate}}"-->
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name ="ListOne" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OldPanelsTemplate}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name ="LisTwo"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OldPanelsTemplate}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks that really solved the problem but as a personal preference i just preferred the converter solution to avoid losing datacontext in content presenter (Thanks Again )

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by merging them in one template like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NewOldPanelsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type VM:CustomPanelBoard}">
    <Grid Height="60">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Height="60" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Width="35" Background="Blue"
                Margin="0 0 2 0" >
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" 
                        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                Converter={StaticResource IncrementerConverter}}" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <!-- To have same template for new and old panels we had the two elements (combobox and textblock) for distribution system and toggle visibility by converters according to their groupbox title -->
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValidDistributionSystemsForPanel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                  IsHitTestVisible="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" IsEnabled="{Binding DistributionSystemNotAssigned}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DistributionSystemTemplate}" 
                  Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Header,Converter={StaticResource NewPanelsTemplateVisibilityConverter}}">
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DistributionSystemName}"
                   Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Header,Converter={StaticResource OldPanelsTemplateVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Number of available ways: "/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding NumberOfAvailableWays}" />
    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

and control the visibility of variable parts(ComboBox and TextBlock in my case) with converters like this :

```
 public class OldPanelsTemplateVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((string)value == "Old Panels")
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}


public class NewPanelsTemplateVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((string)value == "Old Panels")
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }}
```

The solution above is based on that each of my listboxes is surrounded by groupbox with certain header (In other cases you may want to use ListBox Names in the converter as visibility toggle)
Thanks to @PavelAnikhouski for the idea of converters.

Also i tried the solution of DataTemplateSelector proposed by @SamTheDev and it worked also (Thanks @SamTheDev), but i preferred the converter solution because i didn't feel comfortable with the idea of losing datacontext through using content presenter (The bottom line here is both solutions work and no one is more elegant it is just personal preference)